# how to bundle handlers in the handlerManager?

Tags: events, gwt, handler

is there a option to bundle different eventhandler in one javafile?

Like:

```java
public interface MyHandlerr extends EventHandler {
void myEvent1(Event1 event);
void myEvent2(Event2 event);
}
```

in the moment i have  for each event one handler....but i'm not happy with it.

greetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `EventHandler` interface for handling multiple events

```
public interface MultipleEventsHandler extends EventHandler {
    void onMyEvent(MyEvent event);
    void onMyOtherEvent(MyOtherEvent event);
}
```

Then in your event classes you can define which of the methods should be called

```
public class MyEvent extends GwtEvent<MultipleEventsHandler> {
    public static final Type<MultipleEventsHandler> TYPE = new Type<MultipleEventsHandler>();

    @Override
    public Type<MultipleEventsHandler> getAssociatedType() {
            return TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatch(MultipleEventsHandler handler) {
            handler.onMyEvent(this);
    }
}

public class MyOtherEvent extends GwtEvent<MultipleEventsHandler> {
    public static final Type<MultipleEventsHandler> TYPE = new Type<MultipleEventsHandler>();

    @Override
    public Type<MultipleEventsHandler> getAssociatedType() {
            return TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatch(MultipleEventsHandler handler) {
            handler.onMyOtherEvent(this);
    }
}
```

If you just want to reduce number of classes/interfaces then you can put `EventHandler`'s inside your event classes, e.g.

```
public class MyEvent extends GwtEvent<MyEvent.Handler> {

    public interface Handler extends EventHandler {
        void onMyEvent(SomeEvent event);
    }

    public static final Type<MyEvent.Handler> TYPE = new Type<MyEvent.Handler>();


    @Override
    public Type<MyEvent.Handler> getAssociatedType() {
            return TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatch(MyEvent.Handler handler) {
            handler.onMyOtherEvent(this);
    }
}
```